# Hive odbc with prepared statements: ParseException

Tags: python, hive, odbc

Context: Hive3, HDP 3.1. Tests done with Python/odbc (official HDP driver) under Windows and Linux.

I ran the following queries:

1. "select ? as lic, ? as cpg"
2. "select * from (select ? as lic, ? as cpg) as t"
3. "with init as (select ? as lic, ? as cpg) select * from init",

1) and 2) work fine, and give me the expected result. 3 gives me a ParseException :

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:21
>   cannot recognize input near '?' 'as' 'lic' in select clause (80)
>   (SQLPrepare)")

The exact same statements ran with java/jdbc work fine. Note that 2) looks like is a workaround for 3) but it works for this tiny example, not for bigger queries.

Is there something I can do to have ODBC working as expected? Alternatively, where can I find the limits of the ODBC driver?

For full context, the full test code is as follow:

```
cnxnstr = 'DSN=HiveProd'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cnxnstr, autocommit=True)

cursor = cnxn.cursor()
queries = [ 
    "with init as (select ? as lic, ? as cpg) select * from init", 
    "select 2 * ? as lic, ? as cpg", 
    "select * from (select ? as lic, ? as cpg) as t", 
]

for q in queries:
    print("\nExecuting " + q)
    try:
        cursor.execute(q, '1', '2')
    except pyodbc.ProgrammingError as e:
        print(e)
        continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, the Hive ODBC driver has a lot of issues. One of them is that on any error it will send the query as-is to hive, which will complain about the first question mark it founds, no matter what the actual problem is.

If logging is enabled in the odbc driver, the real problem can be found (and there are many of them).